# Is my refrigerator temperature too high?

Tags: chicken

I bought a packet of ready to eat chicken legs, ate a couple, and placed the rest in fridge. Today there are icicles on top of them. 
My fridge temperature is set between 3 and 4.  Is it too low?

Comment: I assume that's Celsius. But the temperature within a fridge varies a lot. If the box was rammed up against the back of the fridge that would be normal. In the meat drawer, maybe a touch cold but not unreasonable. Anywhere else - maybe too cold. But where is the thermometer?

Comment: the thermometer is part of the fridge and has numbers on it, the button is between 3 and 4, there is no degree sign on it

Comment: don't have a meat draw

Comment: icicles in a fridge does sound like something's off

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to answer your question as it is stated.  Get a thermometer and measure the temperature inside your refrigerator over a few days.  It should hover around 37F (2.8 C).